# How can I make checking for unsaved changes when navigating away an html page failsafe?

Tags: javascript, html

My web app has multiple html pages. On a given page (let's call it page A), a user can make edits to a form.  My current method of checking for edits, when the user navigates to another page in my app, is to use the js script below.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    if (changes == true) {
        return "this won't show, as the browsers won't show a custom message for security reasons, but is required";
    };
});
```

When I navigate to another page (let's call it page B) in my app the first time, this works just fine.  However, if I return to page A and make another round of edits, even though the function above runs and my variable 'changes' is true, the browser does not display the warning message that you are navigating away.  Apparently this is because page B is already cached. I am assuming this, because if I force a reload of page B and go back to page A and navigate away, the browser properly displays the warning message.

What is a better solution to ensure the user is always warned they are navigating away from a page with unsaved changes, when navigating to another page?

Update: This is working for Chrome, but not for Safari.

Comment: Where are you defining `changes` ?

Comment: It's a global js var within the code of the page (page A in this case).  The page includes a header, which includes the links to the other pages.  When the user selects page B the second time, a debug of the code within the browser debugger shows the var changes is true, yet the browser navigates to page B, without displaying the warning.  This is why I am assuming it has something to do with page B having already been loaded - as evidence by the fact that a forced reload of page B causes the browser alert to display.

Comment: I have discovered Chrome works consistently, but Safari is experiencing the problem as defined.